# Change the "IP Address" portion of a local Apache2 server to some consistent string

Tags: apache, mediawiki

I have an Apache2 server running in Debian 9.
I am using it to host a custom MediaWiki Wiki.

To navigate to the Wiki I use something of this form "10.200.200.20/mediawiki" where the Apache2 server is running on 10.200.200.20.

This works fine however sometimes the IP Address (10.200.200.20) will change and then everyone on the local network navigating to the Wiki will have to be notified and use the new IP Address which is a hassle.

I wish to change it to something consistent, for example "OurWikiServer/mediawiki" it doesn't really matter that much as long as it can always be found at the same place.

I know this is possible as the MediaWiki installation was previously maintained by someone else who used XAMPP in Windows 7 and it was configured to be found at "stringHere/mediawiki" on the local network.

I have tried changing it in /etc/hosts and can get it changing on individual machines as expected, however have no idea how to get it working network wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to define the IP of this station static. This can be done via reservation in DHCP server or assign IP outside of the DHCP IPs. Also consider adding small DNS server to provide hostname instead of IP